# Ingest data from machines using Tibco JMS queues

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-streaming

I have a scenario where equipment state data e.g. Machine running or Machine Stop from 10000 machines are being ingested into my data platform. Data is only received into a JMS queue when state change of a machine occurs. Lets say from Working state to Stopped state. . This data is streamed into a JMS queue. I use a Spark streaming job to read the message queues and collect machine state data. This has to be loaded into an in-memory store in Spark. There are thresholds for each machine state change e.g. if the machine state changes 3 time in 30 mins it means the machine has more than 3 errors and the machine has to be stopped. The data error count has to be stored in-memory for use by a machine Stoppage API . This process cannot have a write latency and hence cannot be written into a physical table on disk.

We migrated our solution to delta.io. Is there a real-time solution available so that I would not have to write the data into a delta.io physical table but retain all this data in-memeory and process in-memory ? I understand that on the spark context expiring I would lose the state data but can I store data in a shared variable in-memory or lets say an array comprising of error counts of each of the machines that I can use to send out machine stoppage instructions ?

What Spark based solutions do we have ?

We tried using accumulators but note that there are 10000 machines and each machine has 5 variables for various states and errors. It is roughly around 50000 variables. It's ideal to have an array. However, then we need to map which array element has state for which machine. Else variables numbers are huge.